# Problems with amsbook, lstdoc, and sections

Tags: sectioning, errors, listings, compiling, amsbook

The code

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

produces the error messages

`Missing } inserted. [\section{Section}]` and `or forgotten \endgroup. [\section{Section}]`

What is going on there? It works fine if one replaces `amsbook` by `book`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the important information is not the error text itself, but the identification of
where the problem lies.  here is the full error transcript:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.5 \section{Section}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\l@section ...obreak \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hss #2}
                                                  \par \endgroup 
l.5 \section{Section}

?
```

so the problem is in the definition of `\l@section`  this is defined differently --
with different numbers of arguments -- in `amsbook.cls` (7 arguments) and `book.cls`
(5 arguments).

`lstdoc.sty` redefines `\l@section` in a manner parallel to what is defined by
`book.cls`, hence the incompatibility.

this might be patched by inserting these three lines *after* `\usepackage{lstdoc}`
to restore the `amsbook` definition:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@tocline{1}{0pt}{1pc}{}{}}
\makeatother
```

it is possible that other toc levels might also have to be restored as well,
and since this it the first time i've looked at this problem, i can't be entirely
sure that other things in a long document might not also be affected.